# Hide/remove options from a view's grid header filtering

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I've been looking for an approach to remove unwanted values from a views grid column filtering dropdown but I'm not sure if its even possible.

A specific view in our app only displays results where the column will contain 5 values, however the column option set has 20+.  Is it possible to remove the unwanted 15 values from being displayed when the view's filter by function is used?

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/user-interface/filtering#grid-column-header-filteringsorting) does not mention any way the values can be hidden.

I have added a web resource to a view column before, to change text values into an image, however I don't think this is an applicable place to add a script to hide filter by values.

I have developed plugins so not against using this medium if the approach works and does not introduce a performance hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that header filter is not open for customization/configuration. Though MS mention it as Excel like filter, it is not going to give the filter options for only values from current list. It will load the full options list.

When we had such requirements in the past - we have developed a PCF control with grid + filters and used it instead.

Comment: Thanks Arun, it's appreciated - I have started looking at PCF controls today